# What to do when two months after submitting a major revision, its status is still "Editor Assigned"?

Tags: journals, paper-submission

I have submitted a paper to a journal, and received the editors decision (Major Revision). One reviewer suggested minor corrections and one reviewer suggested major corrections. I then resubmitted the paper a month later.

However, two months after submitting the revisions, the status of the submission is still "Editor Assigned". 
I sent two emails to the "handling editor" asking if there is any problem with my paper but no reply.

- What does it mean for a submitted revision to have a status "Editor Assigned"?
- What should you do if that status has not changed two months after submitting a revision?

Comment: Why are you so impatient?  Some academics may take the summer off.

Comment: @GEdgar: … and some journals make sure to know about this, so that they can assign deputy editors or similar. Of course, this may also depend on the field: In my field, where the average review time from submission to receiving the reviews is one month, this would be a major annoyance.

Comment: I have a same problem with Research in Social Stratification and Mobility. We have submitted a major revision with positive comments from both reviewers and after one and half month it is still with editor. We have emailed to EIC several times to request the status but no reply.

Comment: I'm in the same situation. What happened to your paper and how much time it took? Please reply...

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible to know what "Editor Assigned" means without knowing the particulars of the journal's system.  I'll presume this is different than what you saw during the prior round of review, however, and it would in fact be unusual for a paper to be stuck with an editor for two months without going out for review.

If you've emailed the handling editor a couple of times at reasonable intervals and gotten not response, then the next step would be to send a *polite* query to the next level up, which would typically be the chief editors of the journal.  If you get no response there as well, then you've basically got two choices: wait it out some more, or withdraw and submit elsewhere.